# Best way to SCREEN POP user after POST request to URL

Tags: php, javascript, post, curl

Im looking for the best approach to takle the following, I have sorted a solution that will POST info (?from=078103xxxxx&to=020300xxxxx ETC.) using CURL to a URL, upon the user receiving a phone call on their phone <- this part is all sorted, however I need the best way to Screen POP this info and other cross-referenced info (using SQL) info on the users screen, either via the web or intranet.

Basicly, is it possible, if a user is logged onto a URL, say thingy.com/index.php?user=12345 that as soon as the request has been posted to that URL (i.e somebody has rung their phone) that a pop-up is displayed with info on it. If what is the best way???

Any ideas?

Cheers,
B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery, and a 'lighbox' for the popup.  Combined with a server push (aka reverse ajax). Google it.  This can be better than having the script repeatedly requesting for information in a loop forever, though it has it's drawbacks.

**Some info:**
http://biese.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/using-server-push-aka-reverse-ajax/

Comment: thanks and very interesting article - given the circumstances, what would you say is the best option, as if polling is set to 3 seconds, this is obviously a long time to wait after the phone has started ringing, and if polling is set quicker - is this too intensive, there could be 200 + users constantly polling. To me Comet sounds like the one - what do you think???